# Stepper not showing in ToolBar on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar, uistepper

On macOS the `Stepper` is not showing in the `toolbar`. It works on iOS. Does anybody know a workaround?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var value = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Hello")
                .toolbar {
                    // does not show
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Stepper("Test \(value)", value: $value)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems not supported (it is not even present in view hierarchy) - create custom, it's just two buttons and text

Comment: Stepper only from macOS 10.15 [see](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stepper)